# Magento product prices Indexing fails

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I'm having the following error returned when trying to index the product prices...

```
2012-03-16T17:05:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'abs', ( - i.price), IF( = 'fixed', , ROUND(i.price * ( / 100), 4)))), 0) AS `' at line 1
```

Has anyone experienced something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? If so, try removing them one by one (refresh your cache each time) and see one one is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and come back with some more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a colleague had changed a file to make magento custom options work with absolute prices... Reverted and voilá...

Thanks